# function declaration for a generic function return wrapper

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How to declare the function `wraps` that takes any function
and returns a version of it that differs only in returning an object
that wraps the original return type in its prop `value`
... and support generics
[try it here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFJnCAJRIB8JZAUHQCYQDGANjtAGYCucLwAJYB7BAHdsmMPgA8MKBAAewCHEb5YcKinLF0WPESgAFHJgC2EFdlkwqlRDQDeUAG6Y2PCMQBKVnthwACrgEHI0AL4MoJBQAIIwfAIiCMgyQdrAxEHkjlAumNlQUQwsovjAUGJcSFWS0jIJSUKi2uR0APQdUGVwFVVcellQfADWcMJicA7Obh5exAXEYxNTxcWl5ZUgtdUoAIwADIftXVC4wlmd3b39IItznt75JMtw45MIERtd1wqKkAEEEYxD+t22D3cTwehSgcB45gARhBsOsSmdMBouMJsIQmKwONhoOCSIl+C04IQmuSUnQSYpapgyclRAdjqcblsoIoYcR4UiURsgA)

```js
type Fn = (...args: any) => any

declare function wraps<F extends Fn>(): (...args: Parameters<F>) => { value: ReturnType<F> }

type AFunction = <T>(t: T)=> { a: T }


const wf = wraps<AFunction>()
// const wf: (t: unknown) => { value: { a: unknown } }

const y = wf(100)
// got:
// const y: { value: { a: unknown } }
//
// expected: 
// const y: { value: { a: number } }

// as for:
declare const aFunction:AFunction
const x = aFunction(100)
// const x: { a: number }
```

to better explain the subtlety of the question, here's [another way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgWQIZgLwG8BQUoDM4CMAXFADwAqAfABTAnkCUUqlU6US9UAvtnnACYSFGnSiNmrdgCMuvblEyYAJhADGAGyQAnaLgCucNcACWAezhQA7tpQBnUgDkoEAB7AIcZXagBrCCBmuLCIKDRwSAC2EESODCTUAHTJOgDmdiQACjpREB7aDvDIYADajgC6lEwsbFAAbkga%20jFQAEp5%20tpw5OAQpEUoZZU8SphqFnbA1rgEzNa2YHbUAOT4BMsMmAD0W1DjcJPTxFC0JIa%20cGZWcNVS9Y3NJOycUOeX1zwjYxNTVjPtPlQR2oBAADKDNjsoKkzHRtrt9oc-gQAU97k0Ws8znALldLApeDt4S5XJBjBBlCRiYjfv8IBlag0MWiXnB9JFpBBtJ9eN8DrSBHMbPYVvgBBtqT9pkITmI3njboyHpioLJXjj3vivjTpQChbgBCtJtoJVCYXCoTq-gJUUrmbU1fKPgT4cS3GSPJTFJapdbbewmY8HSRjSY4KkeZggA) of presenting it, more similar to my real use case :

```js
type FnMap={
  fn1: <T>(t: T) => { a: T }
  fn2: <T>(t: T) => { b: T }
} 

declare function wraps<N extends keyof FnMap>(name:N): (...args: Parameters<FnMap[N]>) => { value: ReturnType<FnMap[N]> }


const wf1 = wraps('fn1')
// const wf1: (t: unknown) => { value: { a: unknown } }

const wf1Res = wf1(100)
// got:
// const wf1Res: { value: { a: unknown } }
//
// expected: 
// const wf1Res: { value: { a: number } }

const wf2 = wraps('fn2')
// const wf2: (t: unknown) => { value: { b: unknown } }

const wf2Res = wf2('str')
// got:
// const wf2Res: { value: { b: unknown } }
//
// expected: 
// const wf2Res: { value: { b: string } }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1yOGw) work for you

Comment: @catgirlkelly your solution works perfectly, but it doesn't follow the signature `wraps<F extends Fn>`     

if I try to apply (bit.ly/3yo7ULh) your solution to the signature I need, it continues to loose generics... 

however, I like your solution, and arises me a question:     

I typically need to be as explicit as possible to keep track of generics when manipulating types.
 your solution, though, keeps track of the fn generics even if your typing doesn't "mention" the relevant "behind the scenes" generic at all !    
what's the TS feature that let this happen ? thanks !

Comment: to clarify @catgirlkelly , I'm picky with the generic signature because in my use case I'm forced to use the `wraps` function referencing a known function declaration, virtually without the need to pass the actual function as argument.. I'll edit the question to make it clear

Comment: What makes this question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371282/keep-track-of-a-generic-function-type) question also asked by you?

Comment: @outoftouch indeed the two questions are similar, and @catgirlkelly 's solution resembles the answer to the other question of mine you mentioned,    
There's a subtle diff though, in this use case :
I actually need to pass the function type as generic param (and not `<Args,Ret>`), and I enforced this requirement on `function wraps` declaration: it gets the function type as generic param and without the need for any concrete argument..
I'm adding an extra code snippet that is much more similar to my real use case, to better explain my needs