# Keep functions generic context when mapping its type without using a wrapper object

Tags: typescript

I need to map a function from its initial type to the same type except with all arguments being readonly (i.e. to promise to the end user, that the data they pass in as arguments won't be modified).

This is easy, just create a new type with the same args and the same return type, except wrap the args in a readonly type. But problems start once you need to keep the generic arguments of the function intact:

```js
// types for illustration of the problem

export type DeepReadonly<T> =
    T extends (infer R)[] ? DeepReadonlyArray<R> :
        T extends Function ? T :
            T extends object ? DeepReadonlyObject<T> :
                T;

type DeepReadonlyArray<T> = readonly DeepReadonly<T>[]

export type DeepReadonlyObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
};

type State = { numbersField: number[], stringsField: string[] }

function updateState<TKey extends keyof State>(fieldName: TKey, fieldValue: State[TKey]) {

}

// tests

// original function works correctly
updateState('numbersField', [123]) // no error, good
updateState('stringsField', [123]) // compile error, good

// simple solution
type MakeReadonlyParamsFuncSimple<TFunc extends (...args: any) => any> = (...args: DeepReadonly<Parameters<TFunc>>) => ReturnType<TFunc>

// doesnt work
const readonlyUpdateStateSimple = updateState as MakeReadonlyParamsFuncSimple<typeof updateState>;

readonlyUpdateStateSimple('numbersField', [123]) // no error, good
readonlyUpdateStateSimple('stringsField', [123]) // no error, bad

// solution with inferring args and return type in a single type
type MakeParamsReadonly<TParams extends readonly any[]> = {
    [K in keyof TParams]: DeepReadonly<TParams[K]>
}

type MakeReadonlyParamsFunc<TFunc extends (...args: any) => any> = TFunc extends (...args: infer T) => infer R
    ? (...args: MakeParamsReadonly<T>) => R
    : never;

// doesnt work
const readonlyUpdateStateV1 = updateState as MakeReadonlyParamsFunc<typeof updateState>;

readonlyUpdateStateV1('numbersField', [123]) // no error, good
readonlyUpdateStateV1('stringsField', [123]) // no error, bad

// inferring args and type as generic params of type
// based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371282/keep-track-of-a-generic-function-type
type MakeReadonlyParamsFuncWrapper = <TArgument extends any[], TResult>(
    v: (...args: TArgument) => TResult
    ) => MakeReadonlyParamsFunc<(...args: TArgument) => TResult>

declare const wrapper: MakeReadonlyParamsFuncWrapper

// works!
const readonlyUpdateStateV2 = wrapper(updateState);
readonlyUpdateStateV2('numbersField', [123]) // no error, good
readonlyUpdateStateV2('stringsField', [123]) // compile error, good
```

**The question**: how to make `MakeReadonlyParamsFuncWrapper` work but with typings only, without using `wrapper(updateState)` to infer resulting function type, similarly how its done for `readonlyUpdateStateSimple` in the example?

the reason for needing to do this without using a wrapper object is that I could then create a type that would take as a parameter a whole class, for which the type would convert all of it's functions to have readonly arguments using `MakeReadonlyParamsFuncWrapper`.

Comment: This is not currently possible purely at the type level; TS lacks higher kinded types (as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)), so there's no way to express the manipulation you're doing in the type system.  Your wrapper function is using the support for [higher order type inference from generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions), but this, as you saw, requires dropping down to the value level. So for now what you want is impossible.

Comment: Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that does address my question, but could you add any ideas on how to implement the type conversion I am describing in the last paragraph of my question? with the wrapper function if necessary? 

like if I have an object `const stateMutator = { updateState }` how would I go about getting to `const stateMutatorWithReadonlyState = [???]`?

Comment: also theres an interesting library that tries to workaround the problem mentioned in the github issue you linked:
https://github.com/geoffreytools/free-types

maybe that could work?

Comment: Maybe? You could try to emulate higher kinded types in a number of ways; there's a discussion in ms/TS#1213 linked above, and possibly that free-types library does something similar.  But this is really out of scope for the question as asked and comment sections aren't great for exploring topics; if you have a followup question it's best to make a new question post for it (or possibly edit this post to ask that instead of the current question, but scope creep on questions isn't too fun for others)